# Implementing Modular exponentiation in C++

Tags: c++, modular-arithmetic

The following C++ program uses modular exponentiation to compute the quantity ((0.75 + 2.25*(9^((1e+7-2)/2) ))) mod (1e+9+7). This is done using the powxy function, which takes x and y as arguments and returnx x^y mod (1e+9+7). The computed value, 692336617, is incorrect and the correct answer is 192336614. There is a similar problem in computing ((0.75 + 2.25*(9^((300-2)/2) ))) mod (1e+9+7), which I [entered in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%280.75+%2B+2.25*%289%5E%28%28300-2%29%2F2%29+%29%29%29+mod+%281e%2B9%2B7%29). The answer differs from the correct answer, 327873818, but many of the digits are the same. Can anyone explains why the computed values are incorrect or how the program can be changed?

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
 
const int M = 1e9 + 7;

long long int powxy(long long int x, long long int y) {
    if (y == 0) return 1;
    if (y&1) return (x*powxy(x, y-1))%M;
    long long int t = powxy(x, y/2);
    return (t*t)%M;
} 
 
int main() {
    int m = 1;
    long long int n = 10000000; 
    
    int num = 4999999; //num = (1e+7-2)/2 
     
    //int num = 149; 
    long long int res = powxy(9,num)*2.25+0.75; //if num = 149, should equal ((0.75 + 2.25*(9^((300-2)/2) ))) mod (1e+9+7)
       
    
    cout << res;  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `0.75 + 2.25*(..` part is unusual and strange in the context of modular arithmetic, can you elaborate? Is the interpretation that Wolfram Alpha gave that expression the one you actually need?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct expression. The 0.75 + 2.25... comes the formula I derived using the sum of an infinite geometric series, 3+18/8(9^((n-2)/2) -1), which simplifies to 2.25* 9^((n-2)/2) + 0.75. That formula is for the Codeforces problem https://codeforces.com/contest/166/problem/E for the case when n is even and it works for smaller values of n like n = 15 and n = 30 but leads to an overflow error in Python and wrong computations in C++.

Comment: OK, normally when there is something like `18/8` in an expression mod n, the division by 8 is also taken relative to mod n, turning it into a multiplication by the inverse of 8 mod n (which is not one eighth, but 125000001 in this case). I expect that that's actually what you need here.

Comment: That still leaves the calculation of 9^((n-2)/2) mod 1e+9 + 7 which is the main challenge

Comment: I did not find any problem with the `powxy`  that you showed, though `(n-2)/2` only works properly if `n` is even, and 2 has no inverse mod phi(1e9+7) so that division cannot be replaced with a modular multiplication.